# How would I use the Google Docs Research tool in my App Script

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to use the Research tool in Google Docs as apart of my app script, is there a way to call it in my script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell from the Google App Scripts documentation, this is not possible. You might want to [submit a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/list) to Google to add this functionality (new issue button is on the left of the linked page, it's hard to see).